# Winforms how to set combobox Selectedindex with datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a class like

```
public example class {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public object A {get; set;}
    public object B {get; set;}
    ....
}
```

I have a list of examples, and I want to bind the list to a combobox and show by its name.

```
var examples= new List<example>(){ exampleA, exampleB ,exampleC};
comboBox_ExampleSelect.DataSource = examples;
comboBox_ExampleSelect.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

when user choose the item in combobox, I can get the selected object

```
var selectedExample = comboBox_ExampleSelect.SelectedItem;
```

but when I try to set SelectedItem/SelectedIndex by code, it can't work.
I found that the itemsCollection of combobox is null
How do I do?

Update 12/22
I found it might be timing issue. I create combobox manualy.
It work if I assign datasource after add combobox to main form.
Is it necessary?

sample code as follow

```
   public List<Example> _examples = new List<Example>();

   public class GUIBox
   {
       public ComboBox ExampleChooseComboBox;

       public GUIBox()
       {
           ExampleChooseComboBox = new ComboBox()
           {
               Location = new Point(10, 10),
               Name = "comboBox1",
               Size = new Size(100, 20),
               FormattingEnabled = true
           };
       }

       public void AssignList(List<Example> example)
       {
           ExampleChooseComboBox.DataSource = new List<Example>(example);
           ExampleChooseComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

           ExampleChooseComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
       }
   }
   public Form1()
   {

       InitializeComponent();

       _examples = new List<Example>()
       {
           new Example() {Id = "1", Name = "Example1"},
           new Example() {Id = "2", Name = "Example2"},
       };

       var gui = new GUIBox();
       
       
       //gui.AssignList(_examples); ======> fail here

       this.Controls.Add(gui.ExampleChooseComboBox);

       gui.AssignList(_examples);  //======> works here
   }
```

Comment: What code are you using to set the selected item?

Comment: Your code shows you making a List named `examples` but then you assign a collection named `items`. Where does `items` come from and is it null perhaps?

Comment: Another inconsistency in your code is that you show an assignment to `comboBox_ExampleSelect` but then attempt a selection from an instance with a different name: `comboBox_itemselect`. It seems likely that one or the other of these typos could cause _I found that the itemsCollection of combobox is null_.

Comment: sorry, its typo

Answer (score 0):

Usually its common to select an item by the value shown in the ComboBox. Below FindString is used to find an item by the property Name. If say (keeping with the class I'm using) you want to find by Id let me know.

Note, .DisplayMember is not set, ToString value is used as .DisplayMember.

```cs
public partial class StackoverflowForm : Form
{
    public StackoverflowForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Item> list =
        [
            new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
            new Item() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
            new Item() { Id = 3, Name = "Three"}
        ];

        comboBox1.DataSource = list;

        var xx = list.Select((item, indexer) => 
            new { Item = item, Index = indexer }).ToList();
        var selected = xx.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.Id == 2);
        if (selected is not null)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = selected.Index;
        }

    }

    private void SelectedItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item item = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Item;
        MessageBox.Show($"Id: {item!.Id} - {item.Name}");
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I have to find by Id but display in Name, id is unique and name might duplicated but readable.

Comment: I've updated my reply to work with Id property.

Comment: I've updated my question, it seems my main issue is due to I set datasource before add combobox to main form's controls.  It would work if I move datasource setting after adding it to controls. Are there any method can work by setting datasource before add it to controls?

Comment: Why are adding the ComboBox in code, instead drop a ComboBox from the ToolBox onto the form.

Comment: For example, I want implement a case like showing chairs and who is seat on it, each combobox stands for a chair, and I can choose who is seat on it by combobox. And there are rooms with different amount of chairs. when user switch between rooms, dynamic showing the selected room's current chairs' information.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states:

> I try to set SelectedItem/SelectedIndex by code, it can't work.

The intent of the code you posted seems to be making a list of objects of `Example` class and binding that list to a combo box. Your code is assigning `items` instead of `examples` however, and we have to assume the worst about what `items` might be because it's not shown. If you were to follow through with assigning the `examples` collection you should be able to set the combo box as you say by either `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex`. Here's some code where I tested it both ways.

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Example 
            exampleA = new Example(),
            exampleB = new Example(), 
            exampleC = new Example();

        var examples = new List<Example> 
        {
            exampleA,
            exampleB,
            exampleC,
        };

        comboBox.DataSource = examples;
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

        await localCycleWaitCursor();

        // Select exampleB programmatically from index
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;

        await localCycleWaitCursor();

        // Select exampleC programmatically from Example object
        comboBox.SelectedItem = exampleC;


        async Task localCycleWaitCursor()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(new Point(20, 30));
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example class**

```cs
class Example
{
    public Example() => _genID++;

    private static char _genID = 'A';
    public string Name { get; set; } = $"Example {_genID}";
    public object A { get; set; } = $"Object-A-{_genID}";
    public string B { get; set; } = $"Object-B-{_genID}";
}
```